# Digital signal interfering with analog signal and creating false triggers

Tags: wiring, interference

I am in need of some help/advice.

To start the problem.

I am trying to install a sound player on a model train table.  I currently have 8 sound triggers, the switches on four are within 12 inches and seem to have no problem. On the other four, the switches are about 8 feet away. The player uses 5Vdc (analog I presume) for power, when the buttons are pushed the sound plays.

There is also a 16Vdc digital signal power bus that runs around the table as well. On the side paralleling it is about 2.5 inches away (from the switch leads) Also there is a control cable for the digital system using a flat cable rj85 plug cord which runs parallel for 4 feet about one inch away.

The problem I am having is that when both systems are on the 4 sounds all trigger constantly for (approx) half a second on, half second off.

Turning the power off to the DCC (digital) stops the problem. If the DCC is powered but the signal and BOTH the poss AND Neg bus wires are disconnected, No triggering occurs. Connect any one of the three and it starts again.

I do not want to move the switches as they are mounted in the control panel, Removing the DCC is not possible as it is the operating control for the trains.

I do have the possibility to reroute the digital wires in toward the middle of the table and then around to the end. There would be a perpendicular crossing with both cable/bus still. Or, I could try to move the trigger wires in toward the middle.

Would this (hopefully) solve my problem or is there another way to solve this problem? (hopefully with no wires being moved?)

Comment: Couple of things you could try for possibly easy fixes. You could place some capacitors across the switches, which might (if you're lucky) serve to bypass short transitions caused by cross coupling between wires. Another thing you could try is re-wire your switches using coaxial cable, whose shield is connected to a common circuit ground. This could decrease cross coupled noise, as well as other electrical room noise like AC pickup, which of course makes the whole circuit more sensitive. Ultimately, a scope connected to your switch wiring would best tell you exactly whats most effective.

Answer (score 0):

The longer inductive wires act as antenna to the DCC E and H fields caused by voltage & current pulses.

The best solution is to add CM chokes around a twisted wire pair to the audio chip with decoupling cap across the audio chip, not the switch.

The next best is to just put 0.1 to 1uF ceramic caps direct across the sound chip. These are cheap and can be bought in bulk from Digikey , RS, Future Active, or Mouser etc.  Cut leads and solder to,chip. If it already has 0.1 uF caps, then move up to 10uF tantalum.  You can get axial or radial parts < 1/4" or any size you want.

Keep in mind if the switch is rated for >2A , it is not gold plated and will fail from oxidation over time and the polarized  tantalum cap will provide the 10% wetting current needed to burn off oxide.with a low current sound chip. (piezo)

But thinking about it, you probably have micro switches and these are just high impedance logic signals so 0.01 to 0.1uF ought to do it.

In future only use twisted pairs for every thing to reduce EMI in both directions. sender/receiver.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far i will try to get some caps and try adding them. I tryed moving the signal wire and the switch wires (one at a time) to the middle so they would not run parallel and no change. I also moved the sound card so was further away from the bus wires, no change. However in moving the card one of the neg wires broke off. Upon turning on the sound card that sound was still present even with only a pos wire. I inverted one to play when high and had no change but when grounded with the switch it stopped playing with no random triggers.

Comment: that makes sense and supports my answer. EMI triggers from radiated noise gets in long single wires triggering the high impedance logic gate. The cap impedance lowers pulse noise to hopefully an acceptable level when the switch is open. by putting close to end device , your audio switch inputs.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen!  You saved my project. After looking threw my small bin of parts I found a 1uf cap which I used to test Tony's solution and it worked wonders. I had it in for 10 minutes and not one false trigger. Now to get some more caps to fix up the others and the miniature train world will have all the ... 'bells and whistles' ... pun intended, as the sounds that were being affected are train bells and whistles.

Comment: 1uF could be like a crowbar and it's possible anything much smaller would also work wonders like 0.001uF or even less, coupling gap between wires follow inverse square factor.  Is it N scale? next I have a solution for 1mm headlights using fishing monofilament drilled into 3mm LED. with 1k series and tiny diode bridge or easier 30AWG magnet wire  to DCC card

Comment: Ok so smaller than 1uf might be better, i will order a few sizes. It is ho scale, just a small 4x8. The sound card is a wav player from sparkfun with some ambient sound and the 'bells and whistles' to add some life. I am planing on adding a couple of arduino's to animate the grade crossings and use the wav player for the bell as well.

Comment: I was sad to throw out my old HO set after I sold my old house. It had minor basement water damage in the crate and had no time to clean & sell it with tons of tracks and couple dozen cars engines and stuff. but my kids and nephew and I once had immense fun with it. The horn sounded real and loud.